# how to handle Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 0 at Factorl.main(Factorl.java:

Tags: java

```
class Factorl
{
    public static void main(String args[])

    {
              long n,fact=1;       

              n=Long.parseLong(args[0]);

          for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
          {
                 fact=fact*i;
          }

          System.out.println("fact="+fact);
    }
}
```

its showing  Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0   at Factorl.main

Comment: How are you running `Factorl`? Posted code should not generate posted exception; please clarify. `args` may well be empty, but the "index 4" part makes no sense.

Comment: can please post the full error message?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Put more details of the issue that you are facing.

Comment: As commented by @ElliottFrisch looks like you are not passing any argument to your main method.Use `javac filenamehere.java` to compile and `java filenamehere arg` to run

Comment: Is the the code you're running to get this error? i doubt it: the only index i see is 0.

Comment: you should pass a command-line argument as an input for this

Comment: You shouldn't handle this exception, but prevent it

Answer (score 0):

Because you using command-line arguments as an input in your program line

```
  n=Long.parseLong(args[0]);
```

Here you should pass a value for running a program like this

```
  compile by > javac Factorl.java  
   run by > java Factorl 5

    Output:
    fact=120
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `args` array could be empty if nothing is passed to it ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12)). Make a check for its emptiness.

```
class Factorl {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long n, fact = 1;
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Factorial for what?");
            return;
        }
        n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        System.out.println("fact=" + fact);
    }
}
```

I do not personally think that you would be calculating the factorial of a `Long`. The factorials grow very quickly. Note that `20!` is `2.432902e+18`. Thats at huge number.
Now you can refer @MangduYogii's answer for "How to pass command line arguments".